# Change Yahoo API weather condition icons

Tags: android, yahoo-api

I am developing an android App using yahoo API.
I want to change the condition icons to some custom icons.

So I need to receive the weather conditions and then change the `ImageView` or icon based on weather condition.
All condition codes are [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/#codes). But I receive some conditions like "mostly sunny" which are not among them.

What's the idea?

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: I am ready to go. No problem. Even I can retrieve weather conditions as strings like "partly cloudy". There is no problem except there are some conditions out of yahoo API weather condition codes. If I can't find any answers for them I'm forced to use default ugly yahoo weather Icons for them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Try the below snippet and share your thoughts,

```
if (weatherInfo.getCurrentConditionIcon() != null) {                        
                    String name = "images"+weatherInfo.getCurrentCode();                            
                    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", this.getPackageName()); 
                    weather_icon.setImageResource(resID); // your imageview  }
```

Note: Before adding this code you have to replace all default weather icons with your customized icon and give name as like above snippet.

Or you can use this way

```
String[] parts = weatherInfo.getCurrentConditionIconURL().split("52/");                     
                    String[] splited = parts[1].split("\\.");                       
                    String name = "image"+splited[0];                                       
                    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", this.getPackageName()); 
                    image_view.setImageResource(resID);
```

Note: You should load your icon images before implementing this code.

Hope it's help you.